# How to save multiple inputs to the database when the input is in loop laraval 8

Tags: laravel

I am working on a Laravel 8 project. I have a row with 3 inputs and a button which can add more line of row. Doesn't matter how many lines I add only the first row is submitted in the database. Please help me with that. Thank you!

index.blade.php:

```
      <h4>Add Products</h4>
      <form action="{{ url('insert-products') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         @csrf
         <select class="form-select" name="cateId">
            <option value="">Select a Category</option>
            @foreach ($category as $item)
                <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <br>

            <label for="">Product Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="productName" id="quantity2" required><br>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" required>
            <br>
            <div class="customer_records">
            
              <input type="text" name="productName" id="quantity_img2" required>
              <input type="text" name="productVariant" required>
              <input type="text" name="productValue" required>

              <a class="extra-fields-customer" href="#">Add More Customer</a>
            </div>

           <div class="customer_records_dynamic"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success waves-effect" id="type-success">Add Product</button> 

         </form>
```

controller:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
        
        $products = new Products();
        $products->cateId = $request->input('cateId');
        $products->productName = $request->input('productName');
        $products->status = $request->input('status') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
        $products->productVariant = $request->input('productVariant');
        $products->productValue = $request->input('productValue');
        
        if($products->save()){
            return redirect('/categories')->with('status',"Products Added Succesfully");
        }
        else{
            return redirect('/categories')->with('status',"Something went wrong");
        }
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several transmissions involved:

## The request

First of all, you need to make sure that the values are sent at all. Seeing your code, I presuppose that on the request level a single value is being sent. You will need to indicate that there will be multiple values involved, such as

```
        <label for="">Product Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="productName[]" id="quantity2" required><br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" required>
        <br>
        <div class="customer_records">
        
          <input type="text" name="productName[]" id="quantity_img2" required>
          <input type="text" name="productVariant[]" required>
          <input type="text" name="productValue[]" required>

          <a class="extra-fields-customer" href="#">Add More Customer</a>
        </div>
```

Notice the `[]` indicating multiplicity.

**Sidenote**: I would strongly discourage you from hard-coding ids into repeated templates, as they will end up being duplicated, which makes your HTML invalid.

## The application

While the previous section should fix an issue, it's not guaranteed that it's the only issue. It makes sense to debug and see what you have on application-side sent by the request. If you have all the values, then all is well and good. If not, then investigate the reason and fix it.

## The database

You need to make sure that your code attempts to store everything. If so, then a further question is whether it's done successfully. If not, then you will need to debug your code to see what's wrong.